# What JDK version does Snowflake support for Java UDFs?

Tags: java, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

Snowflake now supports Java UDFs:

- https://medium.com/snowflake/new-in-snowflake-java-udfs-with-a-kotlin-nlp-example-e52d94d33468

How can I tell what version of the JDK is Snowflake using?

Answer (score 3):

**2024 update:** *17.x (Preview support for this feature is available to all accounts)*

---

A quick introspection with a Java UDF in Snowflake will answer the question:

```sql
create or replace function jdk()
returns string
language java
handler='MyClass.jdk'
as
$$
    class MyClass {
        public static String jdk() {
          return System.getProperty("java.version");
        }
    }
$$;

select jdk();
```

The current answer is `11.0.8` -- which will probably get upgraded to 17 once its released LTS.

[image]